# Support of a measure on Borel sets not well defined.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \tau$) be a topological space and let $B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$. Let  $(X,B,\mu)$ be a measure space. Then the support of the distribution $\mu$ is defined as :
$$\operatorname{supp}({\mu})=\{x\in X : \mu(U)>0\text{ for all U open neighborhood of }x\}.$$ Now in the [wikipedia article about  Radon measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Motivation), it is written

> A common problem is to find a good notion of a measure on a
> topological space that is compatible with the topology in some sense.
> One way to do this is to define a measure on the Borel sets of the
> topological space. In general there are several problems with this:
> for example, such a measure may not have a well defined support.
> Another approach to measure theory is to restrict to locally compact
> Hausdorff spaces[...]

But I don't see why the support is not well defined when we use the above expression.

Comment: Are you sure that $\operatorname{supp}({\mu})=X\setminus\{x\in X : \mu(U)>0\text{ for all U open neighborhood of }x\}$? So, if we consider the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on the Borel sets of the real line, we will have $\operatorname{supp}({\lambda})=\emptyset$.

Comment: Compare your definition  of support of a measure to the one found here: 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited

Comment: You say "measurable space".  In that setting there is no notion of "open neighborhood".

Comment: @GEdgar You are right. The context was not completely described by just "measurable space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the topological space is not second countable, the definition
$$\operatorname{supp}({\mu})=\{x\in X : \mu(U)>0\text{ for all $U$ open neighborhood of }x\}$$
can still be applied, but it may not yeld what is typically expected of the support of measure.

So while the definition of support of a measure as you posted, or as we can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition), (they are the same definition with slightly different wording) is a definition that can be applied to the general case, it is only **useful** (or **meaningful**) if there are some condition on the topology (such as being second countable).

**Let us see a concrete simple example**:

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $\tau = \{ A \subseteq [0,1] \}=2^X$. Please, note that $(X, \tau)$ is not second countable.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra corresponding to $\tau$. So  $\mathcal{B}= 2^X$.

Let $\mu$ be a measure defined by, for any $E \in \mathcal{B}$, $\mu(E)=0$ if $E$ is countable and  $\mu(E)=+\infty$ if $E$ is uncountable. It is easy to check that $\mu$ is a measure.

**Now what is the support of $\mu$?**  Let us simply apply the definition:

$$\operatorname{supp}({\mu})=\{x\in X : \mu(U)>0\text{ for all $U$ open neighborhood of }x\}$$

But, in our case, for all $x \in X$, $\{x\}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and $\mu(\{x\})=0$. So, for all $x \in X$, $x \notin \operatorname{supp}({\mu})$. So, $\operatorname{supp}({\mu}) = \emptyset$.

**Why is it odd to have $\operatorname{supp}({\mu}) = \emptyset$?** Because, then we have  some $E\subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$, such that $\mu(E) >0$ (just take any uncountable set $E \subseteq X$).

Note that, for this example to work, it was key that any $E$ uncountable could not be written as countable union of the open sets $\{x\}$.

**Remark**:  The notion of support of measure is a minimal set outside of which the measure is null (similar to the notion of support of a function). It means that,
for any measurable set $E$, if $E \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$ then $\mu(E)=0$.  However, using the definition of support of a measure as you posted, or as we can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition), this does not need to be the case for all  topological space, as we have seen in the example above,

Let us now prove that, if the topological space is second countable, then for any measurable set $E$, if $E \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$ then $\mu(E)=0$.

**Proof**: Note that

$$\operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c=\{x\in X : \mu(U)=0\text{ for some $U$ open neighborhood of }x\}$$

A *base* of the topological space is a collection $B$ of open sets such that any open set $U \subseteq X$ is the union of elements (open sets) in $B$. The open sets in $B$ are called *basic open sets*.

So, if there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $ \mu(U)=0$ then there is a basic open set $U'$ such that    $x\in U'\subseteq U$ and $\mu(U') =0$.
On the other, if there is a basic open set $U'$ such that    $x\in U'$ and $\mu(U') =0$, then we can take $U'$ as $U$, and we have that there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $ \mu(U)=0$ . So, we have that: there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $ \mu(U)=0$ if and only if  there is a basic open set $U'$ such that    $x\in U'$ and $\mu(U') =0$.

So, we have that
$$\operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c=\{x\in X : \mu(U')=0\text{ for some $U'$ basic  open set such that }x \in U'\}$$

So, for every $x \in \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$, there is a basic open set $U'$ such that $x\in U'$ and  $\mu(U')=0$. So
$$ \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c \subseteq \bigcup_{U' \in B \textrm{ and }\mu(U')=0} U'\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, if $U'$ is a basic open set and $\mu(U')=0$, then for all $x\in U'$, $x \in \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$. So $U' \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$. So,
$$ \bigcup_{U' \in B  \textrm{ and }\mu(U')=0} U' \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c \tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$ \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c = \bigcup_{U' \in B \textrm{ and }\mu(U')=0} U'$$

So, it is clear that $\operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$ is an open set.

Now, **suppose that the topological space is second countable**, that means, it has a countable base $B$. If $B$ is countable, we have
$$ \mu(\operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c) = \mu \left (\bigcup_{U' \in B \textrm{ and }\mu(U')=0} U' \right ) \leqslant \sum_{U' \in B \textrm{ and }\mu(U')=0}\mu(U') = 0$$

So, for any measurable set $E$, if $E \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$ then $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, it is much more clear. on an other note I don't understand how second countability comes into play. If the space is second countable then the two definitions coincide? Why?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the definition of the measure. "$\mu(E)=+\infty$ if $E$ is uncountable"

Comment: @edamond The two definitions always coincide.  But, if the topological  space is second countable, the support of the measure is "well behaved".

Comment: @edamondo Yes, it was typo. Thanks for pointing it. I fixed it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So well behaved kind of means here that for every measurable set $E\subset spt(\mu)^c$ we have $\mu(E)=0$ right? Now if the space is second countable it means that the space has a countable basis $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, but why does this implies that latter well behaved property?

Comment: @edamondo ,  I have added a **Remark**  to my answer with the details. Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thank you! Looking at your proof also inspired me to do things a bit differently : First start proving $supp(\mu)^c$ is opened. Suppose there exists $x\in supp(\mu)^c$ for which all neighborhood U intersect $supp(\mu)$, then for all those neighborhoods, we have $\mu(U)>0$ so actually $x\in spt(\mu)$ which is a contradiction. Then since $supp(\mu)^c$ is open, for every $x\in supp(\mu)^c$ we have a open neighborhood from the basis $U_x$ such that $x\in U_x \in supp(\mu)^c$. But then $supp(\mu)^c=\cup_{x\in supp(\mu)^c}U_x$ and then we use second countability as in your arguments.

Comment: But then in the citation from OP it is said (I just edited) "Another approach to measure theory is to restrict to locally compact Hausdorff spaces[...]" but following the argument here wouldn't the approach be of restriction to second countable spaces rather than locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Also it is kind of weird since in a book I am trying to read (Modern Methods in the Calculus of variations) it is written **Definition 1.56**. Let $X$ be a topological space and let $μ : M → [0, ∞]$ be a
Borel measure. The support of $μ$ is the set
$supp(μ) := \{x ∈ X : μ (U ) > 0$ for all (open) neighborhoods $U$ of x$\}$ .
**Exercise 1.57**. Let $X$ be a topological space and let $μ : M → [0, ∞]$ be a
Borel measure. Prove that the support of $μ$ is closed. Show also that if $E ∈ M$,
with $E ⊂ X \ supp( μ)$, then $μ (E) = 0$. (->here it seems there is no second countability condition)

Comment: @edamondo Please note that I wrote : "it [the definition of support] is only **useful** (or **meaningful**) if there are some condition on the topology (such as being second countable)".  And, in the **Remark**, I wrote (and proved): "if the topological space is second countable, then for any measurable set $E$, if $E \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$ then $\mu(E)=0$".
However, I never said the the topological space been second countable would the only condition capable of ensuring that, for any measurable set $E$, if $E \subseteq \operatorname{supp}({\mu})^c$ then $\mu(E)=0$".

Comment: @edamondo  Please note that in the citation of the OP it is said : " Another approach to measure theory is to restrict to locally compact Hausdorff spaces, and only consider the measures that correspond to positive linear functionals on the space of continuous functions with compact support (some authors use this as the definition of a Radon measure)". It was never said that it was enough just to consider the topological space to be a locally compact space. It is also necessary to restrict the type of measure under consideration.

Comment: @edamondo  By the way, the example presented in my answer is a locally compact Hausdorff space, however the measure does  **not** correspond to a positive linear functional on the space of continuous functions with compact support.

Comment: @edamondo If **Exercise 1.57** is written as you wrote it here in the comments and there is no previous restriction on the book (kind of "from here on we are going to consider topological spaces to be ...  and / mesures to be...) , then  **Exercise 1.57** is incorrect and you have a counter-example (the example in my answer).

Comment: @edamondo , Regarding **Exercise 1.57**: It is true, in the general case, that the support of $\mu$ is closed (its complement is open). But the second part (Show that if $E \in M$, with $E\subseteq X \setminus \textrm{supp}(\mu)$, then $\mu(E)=0$) is not true in the general case and you have a counter-example (the example in my answer).

Comment: It doesn't correspond to a locally compact linear functional since $\exists f_n\in C_c([01])$ with $\|f_n\|_{max}=1$ but $\int f_n d\mu = \infty$ for all $n$. $f\equiv 1$ would work here but even if the domain was not compact we could build the sequence. Now I just have to verify that the well-behaved property also hold if the space is locally compact and the measure corresponds to a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$. Thank you for the help you provided

Comment: @edamondo You need to consider $C_c(X)$ in the topology used in the example, not in the usual topology of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @edamondo In the example in my answer, the space $(X, \tau)$ is locally compact. In this space,  $K$ is compact iff $K$ is finite. So, $f \in C_c(X)$ iff the support of $f$ is a finite set.  Let $\mu$ be the measure presented in the example.
Note that if $f \in C_c(X)$ then $\int f d\mu = 0$. So, 
if  $\mu$ corresponds to a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$, then such functional will be identically zero. So $\mu$ would be identically zero. Contradiction, since $mu$ is not identically zero. So, $\mu$  does not correspond to a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$.

Comment: I see, very nice

Answer (score 1):

Support  is defined in that article as the smallest closed set $S$ such that $\mu (S^{c})=0$. This is the usual definition of supprt and it is the most convenient. With this definition the complement of the support is the largest open set of measure $0$. If you consider the collection  of all open sets of measure $0$ their union is cetainly open but it may not have measure $0$ since an uncountable union of sets of measure $0$ need not have measure $0$. That is the reason why not every Radon measure has a support.  On any second countable topological space every Radon measure has  a support.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot connect the dots. Why does the fact that the uncountable union of open sets with $0$-measure might have positive measure implies that the support is not well defined?